# Best Practices using Firebase (Saving)

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, save

I'm currently making a online mobile game. It's like an online Idle Clicker.

In order to save the data I will use firebase. I'm still deciding if I should use the "Realtime Database" or " Cloud Firestore". (If any of you could help me too I would appreciate).

My main question is: **When should I save my data ?**

Saving the data every second is crazy because I will spend millions of euros. Even saving the data every minute seems not a viable solution to me.

I have searched and I can save the game everytime the user press the Home Button to leave the app. What if the user is playing and the phone dies?

Is there any other better solution that I am not thinking of ?

Thank you very much, Gonçalo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [OnApplicationQuit()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html) for this. It's called whenever your game is closed. It won't be called if the device loses power though, so if you're worried about that you could start a timer when the game is opened and do autosaves every 10 minutes or on certain scene switches (if the player exits to the main menu for example).

[This thread](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1109150/unity-android-suspendresume-and-quit-behaviour.html) has more info on the topic that you may find useful.

Comment: What if the user presses the button home and then quit the app.
Will the OnApplicationQuit() be called anyway ?

Comment: As long as the app is closed, OnApplicationQuit() will be called. When you press the home button, depending on the device, the app maybe be paused and minimized, in which case OnApplicationPause() will be called instead. So that may be the better method for you.

I use OnApplicationQuit() for my apps though, without issue.